# How do I link with cmocka?

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, gnu-make, cmocka

I am using Eclipse under Ubuntu.

I just installed cmocka:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/cmocka.pc
-- Installing: /usr/lib/cmake/cmocka/cmocka-config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/lib/cmake/cmocka/cmocka-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/include/cmocka.h
-- Installing: /usr/include/cmocka_pbc.h
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libcmocka.so.0.3.1
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libcmocka.so.0
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libcmocka.so
```

When I build a simple test project, I get linker errors. From this code

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <cmocka.h>

#include "factorial.h"

static void test_factorial_zeo()
{
    assert_int_equal(factorial(0), 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const UnitTest tests[] =
    {
            unit_test(test_factorial_zeo),
    };

    return run_tests(tests);
}
```

I get these errors:

```
make all 
Building target: unit_test_C_code_example_project
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "unit_test_C_code_example_project"  ./test_scripts/test_factorial.o  ./software_under_test/factorial.o   
./test_scripts/test_factorial.o: In function `test_factorial_zeo':
/home/me/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug/../test_scripts/test_factorial.c:10: undefined reference to `_assert_int_equal'
./test_scripts/test_factorial.o: In function `main':
/home/me/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug/../test_scripts/test_factorial.c:20: undefined reference to `_run_tests'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [unit_test_C_code_example_project] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

So, it seems that I ought to add the cmocka library to the linker path. But then I get

```
make all 
Building target: unit_test_C_code_example_project
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "unit_test_C_code_example_project"  ./test_scripts/test_factorial.o  ./software_under_test/factorial.o   -llibcmocka.so.0.3.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcmocka.so.0.3.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [unit_test_C_code_example_project] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I get the same results with libcmocka.so.0.3.1, libcmocka.so.0 and libcmocka.so

Obviously, I am doing something very basic wrongly, but what?

```
ls -lAF /usr/lib/libcmocka.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14 Oct 21 15:03 /usr/lib/libcmocka.so -> libcmocka.so.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Oct 21 15:03 /usr/lib/libcmocka.so.0 -> libcmocka.so.0.3.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77216 Oct 21 15:02 /usr/lib/libcmocka.so.0.3.1*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-with-g-linker-cannot-find-library-734085/) and will quote from it:

> The -L option works like a search path for libraries, just like $PATH
>   in the shell is a search path for executable files.
>
> And just like the shell has a default search path, the linker also has
>   a default library search path, with should include /usr/lib. So you
>   should not even need to have to use a -L/usr/lib option. The reason
>   why that did not work for you is that you use a full path with the -l
>   option.
>
> **Normally with the -l option the "extension" is left out from the file
>   name, as well the lib prefix, and the directory**.

So, in my case, I told Eclipse to link with `cmocka`, which caused the makefile to be generated with this command

```
gcc -L/usr/lib -o "unit_test_C_code_example_project"  ./test_scripts/test_factorial.o  ./software_under_test/factorial.o   -lcmocka
```

which links successfully.

Of course, I *knew* this , but had forgotten it. D'oh!